# running python script on windows IOT rpi

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi2, iot, windows-iot-core-10

I have rpi 2 running windows IOT and I want to run python script on it. unfortunately I am having this error after the deploy

I wrote the script using visual studio 2015 as a windows iot core background application.

The error it gives me is

```
Severity   Code   Description   Project   File   Line   Suppression State
Error
DEP3400 : Visual Studio could not enable network loopback and
cannot determine the state of network isolation exemption. 
 Calls to local network services might be blocked, and local network

 debugging tools might not work. The service returned the following error: 
(0x00000005) Exception of type 
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ImmersiveProjectServices.Shared.FirewallShimException'
 was thrown.
```

the output is

```
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32
\backgroundTaskHost.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'.
Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32
\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32 \msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32legacy.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
 The thread 0xf1c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\procthreadexthost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MrmCoreR.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\actxprxy.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\biwinrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppxLayouts\HELLOFMLVS.Release_ARM.aaaa\pyuwpbackgroundservice.dll'.
 Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.24123.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vcruntime140_app.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.24123.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\msvcp140_app.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppxLayouts\HELLOFMLVS.Release_ARM.aaaa\Python35.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.24123.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vccorlib140_app.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32legacy.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Mon Jun 27 23:00:59 2016: Starting Py_Initialize
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CryptoWinRT.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Mon Jun 27 23:01:06 2016: Finished Py_Initialize
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MinUser.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Web.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Python debugger is present
Python arguments: Python.exe visualstudio_py_remote_launcher.py 8116 34a2c836-d62f-4c7a-9a3d-4aa7db7e74ff StartupTask.py
Mon Jun 27 23:01:08 2016: Starting Py_Main...
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppxLayouts\HELLOFMLVS.Release_ARM.aaaa\PythonHome\DLLs\_socket.pyd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppxLayouts\HELLOFMLVS.Release_ARM.aaaa\PythonHome\DLLs\select.pyd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppxLayouts\HELLOFMLVS.Release_ARM.aaaa\PythonHome\DLLs\_ssl.pyd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppxLayouts\HELLOFMLVS.Release_ARM.aaaa\PythonHome\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
2016-06-27 23:01:24.180903: Remote launcher starting ptvsd attach wait with File: StartupTask.py, Port: 8116, Id: 34a2c836-d62f-4c7a-9a3d-4aa7db7e74ff

'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppxLayouts\HELLOFMLVS.Release_ARM.aaaa\PythonHome\DLLs\_ptvsdhelper.pyd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wshbth.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nlaapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[3828] backgroundTaskHost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[3828] python @ tcp://169.254.21.250:8116/?sd=C

%3a%5cUsers%5caaaa%5cdocuments%5cvisual+studio+2015%5cProjects%5cHELLOFML%5cHELLOFML&td=C%3a

%5cData%5cUsers%5cDefaultAccount%5cAppxLayouts%5cHELLOFMLVS.Release_ARM.aaaa&host=uwp' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/python and Deploy your Python app to your Windows IoT Core device following https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/python?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question should first of all be asked at [Raspberry Pi StackExchange Forum](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).

And from the the Error Messages that both of you seem to be having is somehow your network interfaces such as **Loopback Addresses** cannot be accessed using the codes that have been written with Visual Studio. With Linux kernel based system you generally need to run your code with the help of `sudo` which might be synonymous to **Windows: Run as Admin** try running your code as Admin and maybe it should work out. And also you might need to overrun your Firewall settings if there are any on your Windows IoT core